# how a client switches from provider to consmure openldap centos 7

Tags: openldap, replication, centos7, master-slave

I have setup a basic provider/consumer and client openldap on centos 7. Data does get replicated to the consumer when I add something to the provider and it is all synced up. The client can read info from the master(provider). Now I like to turn off the provider and see if the client will read from the consumer. I can use authconfig --ldapserver="ldap://consumer..." --update but that will not be practical if we have many clients and needs to be instantaneous. Could anyone please tell me how to switch a client from reading from the provider to reading from the consumer automatically. Thans

Answer (score 0):

This would include both servers on the client to look at if one is not available:
authconfig --ldapserver=simple-provicder.example.com,simple-replicator.example.com --update

I had the full ldap://simple-relicator.example.com which was the mistake, now I can switch off the master and it sees the replicator.